# Overriding method to create a subclass

Tags: oop, processing

NOTE: A cumulative histogram is a histogram in which each value is added to the sum of the values that have gone before, for example if there are 3 apples, 2 bananas and 6 oranges, then then numbers in the normal histogram will [3,2,6] but in a cumulative histogram they will be [3,5,11].

**Question:** Create a subclass of Histogram called CumulativeHistogram. I only need to override the toString() method to solve the problem.

```
class Histogram
{
public char symbol = '*';
protected String[] categories;
protected int[] frequencies;

public Histogram(int numCategories)
{
categories = new String [ numCategories ];
frequencies = new int [ numCategories ];
for (int index = 0; index < numCategories; index++) {
categories[index] = "unlabeled";
frequencies[index] = 0;
 } 
}

public void setCategory(int index, String name, int frequency)
{
categories[ index ] = name;
frequencies[ index ] = frequency; 
}

public String toString()
{
String result = "";
 for (int index = 0; index<categories.length; index++){
 result+=categories[index] +": ";
 result+=repeatSymbol(frequencies[index]);
 result+="\n";
}
return result;
}

protected String repeatSymbol(int numTimes)
{
String result = "";
for (int index = 0; index <numTimes; index++)
result += symbol;
return result;
}
}
```

**Here is a template for the class:**

```
class CumulativeHistogram extends Histogram {

 public CumulativeHistogram(int numCategories) {
     super(numCategories);
 }

 public String toString() {
     //*****fill in this method
   }
 }
```

**Some test code**

```
Histogram hist = new Histogram(3);
hist.setCategory(0, " Apples", 4);
hist.setCategory(1, "Bananas", 2);
hist.setCategory(2, "Oranges", 5);

println( hist );

CumulativeHistogram hist2 = new CumulativeHistogram(3);
hist2.setCategory(0, " Apples", 4);
hist2.setCategory(1, "Bananas", 2);
hist2.setCategory(2, "Oranges", 5);

println( hist2 );
```

**And its output**

```
 Apples: ****
Bananas: **
Oranges: *****

 Apples: ****   
Bananas: ******
Oranges: ***********
```

Comment: There's no question here, other than an implied "Can someone do my homework for me?". The answer to that is, no.

Comment: the question is how to override a method?? and this isnt homework, stop being so arrogant.

Comment: The answer is in the text then. The bit where it says "Fill in this method". That's the override in action. Write the code to perform whatever functionality you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare another counter outside the loop, incrementing with the loop, and use that with the index as such:

```
result+=repeatSymbol(frequencies[index]+counter);
counter+=frequencies[index];
```